# Calculate results for standingssystem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm currently building my first Rails app. It's an app to enter the results of a sports competition (for a go kart championship). After entering the results, the standing for the championship should be calculated automatically.

I've created a few models to structure the app:

- Races
- Heats (one Race, consists of multiple Heats)
- Results (one Heat has multiple Results for Drivers)
- Drivers

Currently i'm implementing a view to calculate the standing, but i'm kinda stuck. Ideally the results are shown as below:

[Driver standing (screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJmNp.jpg)

The Drivers show up in rows and the Heats show up in columns. The last column calculates the results of all the Heats for that specific Driver (this is just a sum of all the results).

Currently i'm displaying the Drivers through an each loop. However i'm not sure how to loop through the Heats to display the columns and also make sure that the rows inside that column correspondent with the correct Driver.

Can I use separate each loops for this functionality? Or do I need to create one Active Record to display the desired information in one Query?

I'm currently using the following Results Controller:

```
def race
    @ranking = Ranking.find(params[:race])
    @results = Result.joins(:heat).where(:heats => {ranking_id: params[:race]}).group(:driver_id)
    @heats = Heat.where(ranking_id: params[:race])
    @fastest_racelap = Result.where(heat_id: @heats).where.not(laptime: nil).order(:laptime).first
end
```